# AddEventListener() transition end callback in different browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Browsers have different transition end callbacks. So, I must create a **addEventListener()** to each.

```
addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
  // the same below
});

addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', function() {
  // the same above
});
```

But I don't like my code in this way. **Why is not working when I write that way??:**

```
addEventListener('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd', function() { });
  // thing
});
```

The above does not work on any browser. The first one works.

Is there any better way? Any suggestions?

Comment: If you take a look at the [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FEventTarget.addEventListener) function you will see that your code is not working, because the function is not defined this way. Your argument `'transitionend webkitTransitionEnd'` is only a string. If there were an overloaded function that would take an array like `target.addEventListener(["typ1", "type2"], listener);` you could pass an array of string. But there is none.

Comment: I just simplified and removed the element. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by `I just simplified and removed the element`.  To better understand your question i need more information. Why do you want to handle the different transitions with multiple eventListeners? What is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: I want a cross-browser transition end callback. Like I said "Browsers have different transition end callbacks. So, I must create a addEventListener() to each.".

But my code is ugly that way.

Comment: I just want to know if it could be better.

Comment: Do you mean [css3-transitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/)? I do not understand what a cross browser style has to do with how you wire up the events in javascript. Also why not use something that is already offering a cross-browser solution or (maybe by using [a tool that generates vendor-prefixes](http://css3generator.com/)) ?

Comment: No! That's not what I'm talking about! I'm talking about JavaScript only.
Different transition end callbacks: transitionend", "webkitTransitionEnd", "mozTransitionEnd"...

Answer (score 2):

addEventListener only takes one event, so you have to write them seperately. You could iterate over a list to make it at least look smaller

```
["transitionend", "webkitTransitionEnd", "mozTransitionEnd"].forEach(function(transition) {
     document.addEventListener(transition, handler, false);
});

function handler() {
    // thing
}
```